# How to fully redirect to another page?

Tags: php, redirect

How to **fully redirect** to another page *not use header*? I use in contact form

```
$subject = "$name for $type";
$mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
// Send email, if something goes wrong, kill programm and return error message
mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $mailheader) or die("<div class=\"alert alert-error\">Something went wrong, please try again.</div>");
// If all's well, return success page
//header("Location:http://www.test.com/success"); /* Redirect browser */
//exit();
```

But its not working, actually the browser just on contact page but success send message BUT not redirect to http://www.test.com/success page. Please help thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect using `JavaScript`

```
<script>
    location = 'http://www.test.com/success';
</script>
```